# HTTP Response is corrupting the return string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller action in web api that return string token as below.Howver, the problem is whenever there is '/' appear in server side response string, at client side I always get '/' instead where '\' is addition to original string. How can i get rid of it?

[image]

```
public string GetTrackProfile()
 {
    string token="0Q2l7m4dAekjCt/yIxk0txzyZAxjZMYZq6+OAXHPNorrel7hez2vnkLe61Mf2ZLL";
    return token;
 }
```

**client side response**

0Q2l7m4dAekjCt/yIxk0txzyZAxjZMYZq6+OAXHPNorrel7hez2vnkLe61Mf2ZLL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this string is part of an HTTP header, then you should be aware that according to the [RFC 2616 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.2) `/` is considered as a separator character and must be properly escaped (which is what the Web API does for you by prepending it with `\`):

> Many HTTP/1.1 header field values consist of words separated by LWS or
>   special characters. These special characters MUST be in a quoted
>   string to be used within a parameter value (as defined in section
>   3.6).
>
> ```
>    token          = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or separators>
>    separators     = "(" | ")" | "<" | ">" | "@"
>                   | "," | ";" | ":" | "\" | <">
>                   | "/" | "[" | "]" | "?" | "="
>                   | "{" | "}" | SP | HT
> ```

---

UPDATE:

According to the comments, this string is part of a JSON serialized response. It is properly encoded. Let's take the following example:

```
var json = {"d":"a\/b"};
alert(json.d);​
```

When you [execute this code](http://jsfiddle.net/ztFze/1/) the correct string is shown - `a/b`. So this is a perfectly normal behavior.

Comment: no this is not part of the header. the string is being sent in response.

Comment: What media formatter are you using to serialize the response? What Content-Type?

Comment: Content-Type:application/json
using asp.net wep api default json seraliazer

Comment: How does the exact JSON response look like? This seems normal to me.

Comment: response is like        0Q2l7m4dAekjCt\/yIxk0txzyZAxjZMYZq6+OAXHPNorrel7hez2vnkLe61Mf2ZLL

Comment: No, a JSON response cannot look like this. This is definitely not JSON. I have updated my answer. Aren't there double quotes around this response?

Comment: double quotes are there, i thought they are understood        
hmmm, let me execute your code

Comment: Thank you for your help. i was misdirected